# Operator in arguments (Swift)

Tags: swift, operators

I am all new to swift programming and I have tried to make a function which is solving a simple math calculation based on the three arguments, which is the operator type, and two numbers that should be calculated. After a time now I have made it work to an extent that I am satisfied with, in which the code looks like this:

```
func calculation(operatorType: String, number1: Double, number2: Double) -> Double {

if operatorType == "+" {
    return number1 + number2

} else if operatorType == "-" {
    return number1 - number2

} else if operatorType == "/" {
    return number1 / number2

} else if operatorType == "*" {
    return number1 * number2

} else {
    return 0
 }
}
```

As I said, it works fairly well. I have to put in the operatorType with quotation marks as it is a String type, I have tried to get rid of them without any success.

But now to the point:

I tried making the code a bit simpler, I was thinking: it is possible to insert the whole "use the same operator as the argument" in one code? I tried like:

```
 if operatorType == "*" || operatorType == "-"....
 return number1 + operatorType + number2
```

To make it an correct equation, but without any success. So my question is really, I am thinking correct, it is possible to do so, and in that case, how? Even though it is really basic code it would be good to maybe use a more efficient way with less code, that also actually works better.

Thank you!

EDIT: 
Changed the name to one that is not so vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swift does not yet have the Reflection system necessary to fetch arbitrary functions (such as those operator functions you're using) by a String name.

You can improve your code by using a `switch` statement:

```
func performOperation1(operatorName: String, _ operand1: Double, _ operand2: Double) -> Double {
    switch (operatorName) {
    case "+": return operand1 + operand2
    case "-": return operand1 - operand2
    case "*": return operand1 * operand2
    case "/": return operand1 / operand2
    default: fatalError("Unsupported Operator Name")
    }
}
```

To avoid repeating `operand1` and `operand2`, you can store the operator function into a closure variable, and call it once at the end:

```
func performOperation(operatorName: String, _ operand1: Double, _ operand2: Double) -> Double {
    var f: (Double, Double) -> Double

    switch (operatorName) {
    case "+": f = (+)
    case "-": f = (-)
    case "*": f = (*)
    case "/": f = (/)
    default: fatalError("Unsupported Operator Name")
    }

    return f(operand1, operand2)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the information. I have not yet begun looking into switch statements, but after seeing how much it seems to simplify and make code generally more efficient, it clearly is something I have to do. I'll look into it, thank you!

Comment: Swift statements are great, **especially** in Swift. If my answers satisfies your question, please mark is as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

The example you chose is a standard example to explain [*Higher-order Functions*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) (HOM).

A HOM is a function that takes another function (or functor) as input and uses it to fulfil is task.
In Swift one way to write them is to use closures as parameter.

In your example your functions wouldn't take a string to switch the calculation but instead a closure.
In this simple case the function would just execute the closure and return the value.

```
func calculate(op:((Int, Int)-> Int), operandA: Int, operandB: Int) -> Int {
    return op(operandA, operandB)
}
```

Your operator closure would look like

```
let addition: ((Int, Int)-> Int) = {
    return $0 + $1
}
```

or

```
let substruction: ((Int, Int)-> Int) = {
    return $0 - $1
}
```

You would execute it like

```
let result = calculate(addition, operandA: 1, operandB: 3)
```

This might look a bit overly sophisticated and academic, but actually many method we use with Swift are HOM. `map` and `filter` for example. Though they are a little more advanced, as they are generic, meaning they can accept more than just Int parameters. But I don't want to cover it in this post…

Comment: So in that particular case, I should use closures as parameters instead of Strings which I did in my code? I have not actually looked in to this, so I'll try to do that and come back and hopefully understand it better. Thank you!

Comment: @AntonÖdman your question specifics your input is a string representation of the operator. If that's not a requirement, then I suggest you post a new question that explains exactly what you're trying to achieve, and we'll see what we can do.

Comment: *I should use closures as parameters instead of Strings which I did in my code?* Well in that particular case you shouldn't use any of those solutions. neither `let x = performOperation1("+",operand1:1, operand2:2)` nor `let x = calculate(addition, operandA:1, operandB2) ` or anything else. just `let x = 1 + 2`